# How to find a "sufficiently different" RGB?

Tags: colors, rgb

Provided you are given a color in a form of RGB, is there a way to programmatically determine whether it is sufficiencly different from some other RGB.

Say, i'd like to test whether colors are at least 30% apart from one another, how do i do it? Or, put differently, how can i generate a color that is sufficiently different from another color?

Comment: When talking about difference in color, can you be more specific? RGB is not the only way to think about colors - how would you re-frame your question for HSV, for instance?

Comment: What is "sufficiently different"? 30% is kind of meaningless. If thats the case you could test the RGB values of your target color and see if each component is at least 30% more or less than your color. Its hard to tell from your question exactly what you are trying to do, but a color wheel like this might help - http://kuler.adobe.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Treat the RGB value as a point and use the distance formula from geometry.

```
distance = ( (R2-R1)^2 + (G2-G1)^2 + (B2-B1)^2 )^.5
distance > minimun value
```

In the case of wanting 30% difference, make minimum value = the distance of point_1 * .3 from the origin, ie., .3( (R1)^2 + (G1)^2 + (B1)^2 )^.5

Comment: No matter whether this is right or wrong, this answer is just cool :) i'll go test it now

Comment: Looks like CIE76 applied to / shoehorned into RGB ??  Can you do that just like that?

Comment: As primary colors (in RGB), that should make this a 3D vector space as they don't overlap. Think about mutual-perpendicularity in all things you do.

Comment: "Looks like CIE76 applied to / shoehorned into RGB ?? Can you do that just like that?" - no.

Comment: The reason it won't work is it only deals with a magnitude compare on vector values and people won't think a change in saturation is as big as a change in hue. If that's the problem, just dot product the vectors instead.

Answer (score 7):

this is a minefield, because human optical processing is horribly messy.  but what you're asking about is [colour difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) - that page gives various different formulae that can be used to calculate different values that represent the "difference" between two colours.

[update] and here's an [online calculator](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?ColorDifferenceCalcHelp.html) that will apparently calculate those differences for you (it's complicated and links don't change urls, so it's hard to link to, but if you click around it might make sense....)

Answer (score 2):

This is very very subjective. However, I personally think your best chance is to use hue-saturation-lightness (HSL, or HSV for that matter), and try to get a value out of the difference in the values. For example something like:

```
value = a*abs(H1-H2)+b*abs(S1-S2)+c*abs(L1-L2);
```

and try to, with trial and error, find the best `a`, `b`, and `c` constants that differentiate the colors the same amount as your human judgment does. If you know linear regression, you could have some sample colors with the differences you assign and get the `a`, `b` and `c` values with linear regression.

A more appropriate formula may contain differences in power of 2 instead of `abs` for example and more importantly values for `a`, `b` and `c` as functions of the colors themselves rather than constants.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same problem you had with colors, some hours ago, in a different question. Read about HSV (or HSL) in wikipediahttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV: when you transform RGB -> HSV, the H value is the color, S and V are other characteristics.

If you want to know the distance between colors, just measure the H value. If you transform it to a 360 degrees notation, 30 degrees is enough to give you very different colors.

If you want to know it in RGB colors, it gets a bit harder: the values R, G and B can lead you to a grayish "color", not exactly a color.

Comment: Well sometimes same hue but different saturation make colors that ARE different, like pink and red. So just hue can't be enough.